# How to access a OnetoMany join table in JPQL?

Tags: jpa, jpql

I want to write a lttl complicated query in JPQL where i access a OneToMany Join table. I get QuerySyntaxException: Pan_PanRes is not mapped.

QUERY -

```
query = "SELECT p FROM Pan p WHERE p.id IN " +
            "(SELECT p_id FROM Pan_PanRes p_prs WHERE prs_id IN " +
            "(SELECT r.id FROM PRS r where r.pant = :pant))"+                       
            " ORDER BY pr.clD"
```

i tried implementing this concept in MYSQL. It works fine. So i know i am not calling the join table in right way. How should it be called then?

I would like to add MYSQL statement which works fine -

```
mysql> select * from pan where id not in 
(select pan_id from pan_panres where panres_id in 
(select id from panres where pant_id = 3));
```

Thanks...

Comment: `SELECT p FROM Pan p WHERE p.id IN    AND p.id NOT IN ...` does not seem valid syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it myself -

```
query = "SELECT p FROM Pan p WHERE p.id IN " +
            "(SELECT p.id FROM p.panRes prs WHERE id IN " +
            "(SELECT r.id FROM PanRes r where r.pant = :pant))"+                       
            " ORDER BY pr.clD"
```

Where `panRes` is the oneToMany variable name i have used in Pan Class.